# pop() isn't popping the first (last) element of the stack

Tags: c, struct, stack

Disclaimer: It is an exercise assigned that I don't have to hand in, therefore it wouldn't make sense for me to cheat.

I've got a stack of structures:

```c
struct vehicle {
    char plate[11];
    double speed;
    double limit;
};

struct report {
    struct vehicle storage[N_STACK]; //N_STACK = 4
    int n_busy;
};
```

I've defined my push and pop functions:

```c
int push(struct report* stack, struct vehicle s) {
    if (stack->n_busy >= N_STACK) return FULL;
    stack->storage[stack->n_busy] = s;
    stack->n_busy++;
    return OK;
}

int pop(struct report* stack, struct vehicle* s) {
    if (stack->n_busy <= 0) return EMPTY;
    *s = stack->storage[stack->n_busy-1];
    stack->n_busy--;
    return OK;
}
```

I'm supposed to load data from a file into the stack:

```c
int load_vehicles_from_file(char* filename, struct report* stack) {
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) return FILE_ERR;    
    
    struct vehicle s;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s%lf%lf", s.plate, &s.speed, &s.limit) == 3) {
        push(&(*stack), s);
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    return OK;
}
```

Then I go through each element, define who's gone past the limit (+5% tolerance) and write them to an output file:

```c
int is_crime(struct vehicle* s) {
    double percentage = (5 * s->limit) / 100;
    if (s->speed > s->limit + percentage) {
        s->limit = s->speed - s->limit; //exceeding speed
        return CRIME;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

double charge_crime(double speed) {
    if (speed <= 10) return 137.0;
    else if (speed > 10 && speed <= 40) return 695.0;
    else if (speed > 40 && speed <= 60) return 2170.0;
    else if (speed > 60) return 3382.0; 
}

int write_crimes_on_file(char* filename, struct report* stack) {
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (fp == NULL) return FILE_ERR;
    double fine;
    struct vehicle s;
    
    for (int i=0; i<N_STACK; i++) {
        pop(&(*stack), &s);
        if (is_crime(&s) == CRIME) {
            fine = charge_crime(s.limit);
            fprintf(fp, "%s\t%.1f %.1f\n", s.plate, s.limit, fine);
        }
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    return OK;
}
```

main:

```c
int main() {
    struct report stack;
    init(&stack);
    
    char* filename = "cars.txt";
    printf("reading data from %s\n", filename);
    load_vehicles_from_file(filename, &stack);  
    printf("verifying for possible crimes commited...\n");
    write_crimes_on_file("crimes.txt", &stack);
    printf("crimes written to crimes.txt\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Considering the input file:

```
DYD666 110.0 100.0
S99821 80.0 90.0
BAT1 120.0 50.0
KN1GHT 160.0 130.0
PAP313 95.0 90.0
```

I get, in my output file:

```
KN1GHT  30.0 695.0
BAT1    70.0 3382.0
DYD666  10.0 137.0
```

Missing `PAP313 95.0 90.0`. To me it looks like the pop function is not written or used properly(?).

Comment: Your comment says `//N_STACK = 4` but your input file has 5 lines. You never check the return values from `push()` and `pop()`.

Comment: @pmacfarlane shame on me. Considering that I should have had 4 items in the output file I confused the numbers and actually never noticed. I'll fix the return value checks.

Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: So, the problem is solved? Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Having your low-level functions return success/error values is good, but it serves no purpose if you never bother to check those return codes.  Always check for errors.  Never just assume that user data will fit.

Comment: Also, your range-categorizing functions are doing twice as many comparisons as they need to, making them not only slower but also more error-print (i.e. more difficult to avoid introducing errors).  Instead if `if (x < 10) ... else if (x >= 10 && x < 20) ...`, just do `if (x < 10) ... else if (x < 20) ... else ...`  It should end with a bare `else`.